# How to allow touching only in specific area in the scene?

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit, skscene

I want to set touching to be only in part of the screen i have tried to add node layer in the part of the screen that not allowed to be touched and disable the user interactions

```
_mainLayer.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
```

but it didnt work any idea how to do it ?

Comment: Subclass UIView and override - (UIView *)hitTest:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event

Comment: Do you really want to disable touching in a part of the _screen_ or in a part of a _view_?

Comment: thanks but can u explain more

Comment: @rschmidt part of a view

Comment: Dreaming in Binary's answer will work then. However my preference would be to conform to the UIGestureRecognizerDelegate protocol and implement shouldReceiveTouch

Comment: @rschmidt i conform UIGestureRecognizerDelegate protocol and used "- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer * _Nonnull)gestureRecognizer
       shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch * _Nonnull)touch" but can you how exactly can i use to restrict touch in botton of the screen for example ?

Comment: You can use the "touch" parameter to get the coordinates of the touch ([touch locationInView:theView]), and return false if they are inside the region of the view that you want to ignore touches on.

Comment: @rschmidt and sorry if bother you but i cant do well cause i didnt work with gesture before so plz carry with me a little bit i want the area to be like this https://www.dropbox.com/s/ld6lybbrjct22ov/screen.png?dl=0 the number not true just for example how i can do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example of how you can limit touch events to specific regions:

**Swift**

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
    for touch in (touches as! Set<UITouch>) {
        let location = touch.locationInNode(self)

        switch (location) {
        case let point where CGRectContainsPoint(rect, point):
            // Touch is inside of a rect
            ...
        case let point where CGPathContainsPoint(path, nil, point, false):
            // Touch is inside of an arbitrary shape
            ...
        default:
            // Ignore all other touches
            break
        }
    }
}
```

**Obj-C**

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

    for (UITouch *touch in touches) {
        CGPoint location = [touch locationInNode:self];

        if (CGRectContainsPoint(rect, location)) {

        }
        else if (CGPathContainsPoint(path, nil, location, false)) {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: how i can do it in objective c ?

Comment: thanks man but what should "rect , path" value be if i want the area like this https://www.dropbox.com/s/ld6lybbrjct22ov/screen.png?dl=0

Comment: The black area or the gray with the numbers?

Comment: i want to allow touching in the gray area and in the black area i dont the user interaction , sorry if i bothering you still beginner :P

Comment: To allow touches only in the gray area, use `CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.width, height);`, where (0, 0) is the bottom-left of the screen, `self.width` is the width of the screen, and `height` is the height of the gray area.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have enough room in comments to go into extra depth so this is just a quasi-answer.

In your screenshot in comments it appears that you do not want touches to be recognized anywhere in a 200 pixel tall region at the very bottom of the view.

You can have your view adopt the UIGestureRecognizerDelegate protocol and implement the shouldReceiveTouch method. Try implementing that method like so (I actually haven't used Objective-C in a while so forgive me if any of the syntax is off at all):

```
-(BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch 
{
    CGPoint touchPointInView = [touch locationInView:self];

    if (touchPointInView.y >= CGRectGetMaxY(self.bounds) - 200)
    {
        return NO;
    }
    else
    {
        return YES;
    }
}
```

Don't forget to set your gesture recognizer's delegate (in the view's constructor tends to be a good place):

```
gestureRecognizer.delegate = self;
```